# Finding the equivalent binary-number to a given number

Tags: c

**Hello people**,
  Again, trying to create a program in C to help figuring what the equivalent binary-number to a given number is. I had no idea what to do first, I developed a little simple code for it. But the ***problem*** is that I had to put some improvisations into it AS code is (READ BACKWARDS).
So regarding this, the code isn't really complete. Here's the code I came up with ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int x,n;
printf("This program will help you find the equivalent binary-number to a given number \n");
printf("Enter number :");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("The binary number to this number is(Read backwards) :");
for (;;n/=2)
    {
        x=n/2;
        if (x!=0) printf("%d",n%2);
        else {printf("%d\n",n%2); break;}
    }
}
```

Now the equivalent binary-number to *8* is *1000* and the program shows it backwards like *0001* and I have absolutely no idea how to to make it right. **Any thoughts?**

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun It becomes like
`x=n/2;
 if (x!=0) printf("%d",n%2);
 else {printf("%d\n",n%2); break;}
 n/=2;`

Comment: @Dariusz I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Use the shift right `>>` operator to read the number bit by bit.
Then `n & 1` tests if the bit is set or not.

```
  for (;n; n>>=1)
  {
    if (n & 1)
       printf("1");
    else
       printf("0");
  }
  puts("");
```

Comment: Would shifting the bitmask instead be different in terms of speed? Apart from the value of `n` not being lost of course.

Comment: Don't know if there would be a performance benefit. If there is, it would be marginal. Also the code would then need to compute the integer type's bit length (for portability).

Comment: Using `sizeof(n)<<3` to get the no. of bits would serve as the test in the for loop. A simple ternary operator would suffice for printing 1 or 0 instead of the if-else, and `n` wouldn't need to be modified.

Comment: The byte bitlength is platform dependant, it may not be eight bits. Any performance benefit being discussed here is minimal. Unless the loop is repeated a huge number of times, there is no discernable benefit. Your proposed solution is just as valid.

Comment: As a tidbit, `((unsigned char)(~0)==0xff)` can be used to check if the size of 1 byte is 8 bits, as unsigned char is defined by the C standard to be one byte

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand solution would look like this:

```
/* compile with gcc -Wall -Werror -o bprint bprint.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
bprint (int64_t n)
{
  int bit;

  /* Handle negative numbers as positive ones, printing a - sign */
  if (n < 0)
    {
      n = -n;
      printf ("-");
    }

  /* Skip leading zeros. Comment this bit out if you want */
  for (bit = 63; (n <= ((1LL << bit) - 1)) && (bit > 0); bit--);

  for (; bit >= 0; bit--)
    printf ("%c", (n & (1LL << bit)) ? '1' : '0');

  printf ("\n");
}

int
main (char **argv, int argc)
{
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    bprint (j);
  exit (0);
}
```

The first `for` loop within the bprint function skips leading zero bits which are unneeded. The second `for` loop does the printing.

Note that this is far from the most efficient way to do it. A better way would be to note that an int64_t normally takes a string of at most 66 octets (leading minus, 64 bits, terminating zero). One could thus write the bits one by one into a fixed length array of characters, then write the terminating zero, and use `printf` with `%s` to print the result. And a practical function would either take a file handle, a `FILE` pointer, or return a string. Both of these are left as exercises for the reader; the purpose of the above is to show how the bit manipulation works. You could also use fewer brackets once you are confident with operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned  n;
    size_t size = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n);
    char bits[size + 1];
    char *p = &bits[size];
    *p = '\0';
    printf("This program will help you find the equivalent binary-number to a given number \n");
    printf("Enter number :");
    scanf("%u", &n);
    if(n){
        for (; n ; n >>= 1)
            *--p = (n & 1) ? '1' : '0';
    } else {
        *--p = '0';
    }
    printf("The binary number to this number is(Read backwards) :");
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```